# Monotone Likelihood Ratio Ordering

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ $\le$$^{lr}$ $Y$ , suppose we want $X - a$ $\le$$^{lr}$ $Y - b$ as well, where a and b can be any numbers. What conditions should hold for $a$ and $b$?

Edit: I have found out that the likelihood ratio ordering is preserved if a=b. However, what about cases where a≠b? Is it sufficient that $a>b$?

Comment: What does $\leq^{lr}$ means and what did you try?

Comment: It means that $X$ is stochastically smaller than $Y$ in the monotone likelihood ratio order.
What I know so far is that if X1 $\leq^{lr}$ Y1, and X2 $\leq^{lr}$ Y2, and if all of them have log-concave densities, then X1+X2 $\leq^{lr}$ Y1+Y2 is true.
However, I'm not sure if the result can be applied to constants.

Comment: So $X\leq^{\mathrm{lr}} Y$ means that $P(X>c)\leq P(Y>c)$ for all $c$?

Comment: Yes. If $X\leq^{\mathrm{lr}} Y$, it implies $X\leq^{\mathrm{st}} Y$, which means $P(X>c)\leq P(Y>c)$

Comment: Monotone likelihood ratio order is strictly stronger than stochastic order, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_likelihood_ratio).